# Can i get the url of a chrome.exe by its processId?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, .net-core

i want to know what is the URL that is opened in a chrome tab. I have the process and the process ID. My code looks like below:

```
    IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
```

Ps: I'm using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: You could create an extension that grabs that info, then shares it via some IPC mechanism.  I doubt there is a 'direct' way.

Comment: The active tab in the moment that this code runs.